# Solving overdetermined system in numpy when the value of one variable is already known

Tags: python, numpy, system, equations

I'm trying to solve an overdetermined system in Python, using the `numpy.solve` function. I know the value of one of the variables and I know that in theory I can find a unique solution for the system if I can somehow plug in that known value.

My system is of the form `AxC=B`. The variables are split into two groups, one group of N variables and one of T variables (although this does not matter for the math). A is a `(T*N x T+N)` matrix, C is the variables vector, of length `(T+N)`, and B is a vector of length `(T*N)`.

How do I tell `numpy.solve` (or another function in Python, but please don't recommend least squares, I need the unique, exact solution, which I know exists) to use the known value of one of the variables?

A simple example of my system would be:

```
|1 0 0 1 0|     |n1|     |B1|
|1 0 0 0 1|     |n2|     |B2|
|0 1 0 1 0|  X  |n3|  =  |B3|
|0 1 0 0 1|     |t1|     |B4|
|0 0 1 1 0|     |t2|     |B5|
|0 0 1 0 1|              |B6|
```

The values of the elements of B would of course be known, as well as the value of one of the variables, let's say I know that `t1=1`. The dots don't mean anything I just put them there so the characters wouldn't bunch up.

Comment: well in your case, it doesn't matter if you already have the value of `t1`, any simultaneous eqns of form `A.x = B`, can be solved for all the value of `x` as `x = inv(A)*B`. If the solution you are finding is unique, you can check the correctness of your solution by comparing the calculated value of `t1` with the already known value of it.

Comment: There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but can't you remove the column from A corresponding to the variable you know (call that A'), remove the variable from C (call that C'), and recalute B' as B - (column removed from A) * the known value ?

Comment: `..."please don't recommend least squares, I need the unique, exact solution, which I know exists"...` Actually, your example is overdetermined. By definition, you have to use a method such as least squares.  There is no unique, exact solution.  However, Foon's suggestion is the canonical way of doing this.

Comment: I don't believe this particular example is overdetermined, as, for example, row 3 (0 1 0 1 1) is a linear combination of rows 4, 5, and 6 (row 4 + row 5 - row 6). The example may be inconsistent, though, which is completely different than overdetermined... Or, it may even be underdetermined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you need to solve

```
|1 0 0 1 0|     |n1|     |B1|
|1 0 0 0 1|     |n2|     |B2|
|0 1 0 1 0|  X  |n3|  =  |B3|
|0 1 0 0 1|     |t1|     |B4|
|0 0 1 1 0|     |t2|     |B5|
|0 0 1 0 1|              |B6|
```

and you know t1. Then you need to solve

```
|1 0 0 0|     |n1|     |B1| - 1 t1
|1 0 0 1|     |n2|     |B2| - 0 t1
|0 1 0 0|  X  |n3|  =  |B3| - 1 t1
|0 1 0 1|     |t2|     |B4| - 0 t1
|0 0 1 0|              |B5| - 1 t1
|0 0 1 1|              |B6| - 0 t1
```

so that basically you:

- remove the 4th column from the matrix
- subtract the right-hand-side by this 4th column multipled by t1
- remove t1 as a variable

Once you have the appropriate matrices, just call [`numpy.linalg.solve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) (or something similar). I suggest that you don't concern yourself with whether you're "doing least squares", or whether it's unique or not. Let `linalg.solve` find the optimal solution (in the L2 sense); if the solution is unique, then it is unique in the L2 sense as well.

Answer (score 6):

As @Foon pointed out, the canonical way to do this is to subtract a column.

However, on a side note, as your problem is overdetermined, you *have* to use a method such as least squares. By definition, if it's an overdetermined problem, there is no "unique, exact solution".  (Otherwise it would be even-determined - A square matrix.)

That aside, here's how you'd go about it:

Let's take your example equation:

```
|1 0 0 1 0|     |n1|     |B1|
|1 0 0 0 1|     |n2|     |B2|
|0 1 0 1 0|  X  |n3|  =  |B3|
|0 1 0 0 1|     |t1|     |B4|
|0 0 1 1 0|     |t2|     |B5|
|0 0 1 0 1|              |B6|
```

As you noted, this is overdetermined. If we know one of our "model" variables (let's say `n1` in this case), it will be even more overdetermined.  It's not a problem, but it means we'll need to use least squares, and there isn't a completely unique solution.

So, let's say we know what `n1` should be.

In that case, we'd re-state the problem by subtracting `n1` multiplied by the first column in the solution matrix from our vector of observations (This is what @Foon suggested):

```
|0 0 1 0|     |n2|     |B1 - n1|
|0 0 0 1|     |n3|     |B2 - n1|
|1 0 1 0|  X  |t1|  =  |B3 - 0 |
|1 0 0 1|     |t2|     |B4 - 0 |
|0 1 1 0|              |B5 - 0 |
|0 1 0 1|              |B6 - 0 |
```

Let's use a more concrete example in numpy terms.  Let's solve the equation `y = Ax^2 + Bx + C`.  To start with, let's generate our data and "true" model parameters:

```
import numpy as np

# Randomly generate two of our model variables
a, c = np.random.rand(2)
b = 1
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 6)

y = a * x**2 + b * x + c
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, y.size)
y += noise
```

First, we'll solve it _without) the knowledge that `B = 1`.  We could use `np.polyfit` for this, but to lead into the next bit, we'll use a lower-level approach:

```
# I'm a geophysist, so I tend to use Gm=d instead of Ax=b
G = np.column_stack([x**2, x, np.ones_like(x)])
d = y

m, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(G, d)

print "Ideally, this would be 1: ", m[1]
```

As you can see, we'll get something close to, but not quite 1.  In this case (I didn't set the seed, so this will vary), the model parameters returned are

```
[ 0.13392633,  0.97217035,  0.33645734]
```

While the true parameters are:

```
[ 0.14592752,  1.        ,  0.31349185]
```

Now let's take the fact that we know `b` exactly into account.  We'll make a new `G` with one less column and subtract that column times `b` from our observations (`d`/`y`):

```
G = np.column_stack([x**2, np.ones_like(x)])
d = y - b * x
m, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(G, d)
```

Now `m` is `[a, c]` and we've solved for those two variables using our knowledge of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the remove-a-column trick is exactly what I needed. The particular structure of my example, particularly it not having full rank, is representative of the class of problems I'm working on. Knowing one of the variables makes these problems analytically solvable with a unique solution, the remove-a-column trick lets me successfully find that solution using numpy.linalg.solve, so my question was answered.